# Unable to Verify .well-known/acme-challenge/ In CWP7 on CentOS 7.5

Tags: centos7, lets-encrypt

I have a VmWare VPS and Using CWP7 on CentOS 7.5 and I am using apache server only . I have successfully installed Lets Encrypt SSL for my server FQDN (host.domain.com) .

When I am using certbot for new SSL for another domain (realmart.net), it's showing error and unable to verify the location http://realmart.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/ .

When I am accessing the URL , it;s showing the error below :

"You don't have permission to access /.well-known/acme-challenge/ on this server."

I have set the write permission for that location But another directory is accessible: http://realmart.net/.well-known/

Then I try with https://www.sslforfree.com/ for that certificate and I have created /.well-known/acme-challenge/ manually with the right permission then it's showing the same error.

Is there any way to verify or browse the location http://realmart.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/ ?

Please suggests ...

Story: Few days ago CWP admin Team has been removed LetsEncrypt module and added AutoSSL . I think CWP Team block that's type of verification that user will be used to AUTO SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Try uploading your verification files in 
`/usr/local/apache/autossl_tmp/.well-known/acme-challenge/`

Comment: Very useful to know when using CWP and you have to use pki-validation as folder to validate SSL. I was trying to create it in the wrong location.